# Android, two apps one database?

Tags: android, database

We are developing an android app and we want to make two versions, pro and free. The problem is that our apps use a database which we want to be available for both apps.Is it possible?

I mean, the client downloads the free app, and he uses it. Then he decides to buy the pro version, would it be posible to pass the data from free version to pro version?

Thanks

Comment: There is a check mark under the vote counter of the answer. Click it to mark the correct answer.

Comment: ok thanks i didnt know what i was thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a content provider if you want

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 14):

Two different apps wont be sandboxed from each other and can use the same database provided that they are signed with the same private key and have the same `sharedUserId`. No need to store the database on a shared folder which might cause breach of sensitive data.

Add:

```
android:sharedUserId="com.yourprogram"
```

inside `manifest` tag in your manifest files and sign both apks with same key. For details:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: Nice. Didn't think of that one.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP. This question is very helpful. What happens if the database is stored in the free version's directory and the user deletes the free version from their device? Will this automatically delete the database? Or is there an option to remove the app only and keep the data?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think it will delete the database. Non-free version could copy the database to its own folder on first run though. Would that solve your problem?