# Accessing database from two different apps

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

I am creating a Premium edition of an app for which I already released a free Lite edition. I want to either transfer the data from the Lite edition into the Premium edition or have both editions access the same database. [Android, two apps one database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130832/android-two-apps-one-database/) helped answer how to do the later. If the database is created in the Lite edition, what happens when the user installs the Premium edition? Do they have to keep the Lite edition installed in order to keep the data? On the other hand, can I create the database in a location that is independent of either edition but is still sandboxed? Ultimately, I want to be able to allow the user to remove the Lite edition after they install the Premium one but still keep all the data intact. How do I do this? Or am I stuck with making my users keep both editions installed even after they upgrade to the Premium edition?

Comment: You could have it so that when the premium edition is first run, it checks for the existence of the free app's content provider. If it is found, then it copies the entire thing over to one stored in the Premium app. Then the premium app just accesses its own provider instead of the free one from then on.  The only tricky thing with this would be if for some reason the user went back to using the free one, the premium edition wouldn't get any changes they make, but you could handle that by detecting this case in the free app and informing the user or asking if they meant to open the paid app.

Comment: Are you interested in putting the data in a shared location external to the application? If so I can describe options for that.

Comment: @ryan1234 That sounds like what I'm looking for. However, I still want the data to only be accessible from my apps or via a ContentProvider. I would rather not put the data in a shared location which is open for anyone to access.

Comment: @littleFluffyKitty Thanks for the idea. It sounds a lot like what I meant by "transfer the data from the Lite edition into the Premium edition." I will continue to explore that option further.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend at least looking into CouchDB for hosting the data. You create your data as documents (in JSON) and then you create databases that contain documents.

In addition you can create views on your data - http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API. You can pass in parameters to the views to filter data etc.

You can create a sample CouchDB with Cloudant (https://cloudant.com/) or IrisCouch (http://www.iriscouch.com/). I know Cloudant supports HTTP authentication so you can make all your calls look like this from the Android device:

`http://user:password@yourdomain.com/database`

Another option is to look at TouchDB which handles replication from CouchDB for you. https://github.com/couchbaselabs/TouchDB-Android Keep in mind the project is a little behind right now, so I don't think it's production ready, but they're focusing heavily on it this year, so it should be coming along shortly.

Just an option for putting up a shared database with authentication. Then you could host the same data and leave the lite vs. premium stuff strictly in the UI.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. For now, I want to keep it simple and so prefer a solution which stores data locally on the device. I want to add configuration to a future version so that the user can specify the storage location, so I will keep this in mind as an option.